# How to ask user to play again in console F#

Tags: f#

Okay so i'm currently making mastermind in console in fsharp, and im trying to figure out how to ask the user if they want to play again.

```
let main() =
  choosePuzzleMaker() 
  puzzleGuess() 
 c <- guess b [([],(0,0))] 
  while a <> c && d <> 8 do
    c <- guess b [(c, validate a c)] 
    d <- d+1 
  if d <> 8 then
    printfn "GZ! FUCKING MASTERMIND! You completed in %A turns and the code was %A" d a
  else
    printfn "That didn't go well...?"
    printfn "Game Over!"
PlayAgain()
main()
```

where i tried defining PlayAgain() as:

```
let rec PlayAgain() =
  printfn "Do you want to play again? Please type:
1: Yes
2: No\n"
  match System.Console.ReadLine() with
  | "1"|"yes"|"Yes" -> printfn "Alright!!!"
                       choosePuzzleMaker()

  | "2"|"no"|"No" -> printfn "The game is over!"

  | _   -> printfn "Invalid option! Please try again!"
           (PlayAgain())
```

However, that didn't work so my quesiton is:

How would you make the console take a response yes/no and make the program begin again?

Comment: What do you mean, *"that didn't work"*?

Comment: When i tried to run it, the first thing it asked became PlayAgain, then the program ran as expected until the end where it didn't ask PlayAgain

Comment: AFAICT, the program only calls `PlayAgain` once, so that doesn't sound surprising...

Comment: But why does it do that? My intent was to have playagain make the user go back to "choosePuzzlemaker" and then the game would be "restarted"

Comment: `choosePuzzleMaker` isn't shown, so I can't comment on that...

Comment: Maybe you want to call `main` in `PlayAgain` instead of `choosePuzzleMaker` and call `PlayAgain` in the end of `main`?

Comment: ^ Just as the comments say above, are you sure you're indenting `PlayAgain()` correctly in the penultimate line in your first snippet? It should be part of `main()` probably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your problem is a simple indentation mistake. F#, like Python, defines code blocks by indentation. Let me show you an example:

```
// Some variables
let x = 5
let y = 3
let z = 1

let add1_wrong x =
    printfn "Adding 1 to %d produces..." x
printfn "The wrong answer: %d" (x + 1)  // Oops! This is wrong

let add1_correct x =
    printfn "Adding 1 to %d produces..." x
    printfn "The right answer: %d" (x + 1)  // This is correct

add1_wrong x
add1_wrong y
add1_wrong z
add1_correct x
add1_correct y
add1_correct z
```

Try running that in F# Interactive and you'll get the following output:

```
The wrong answer: 6
Adding 1 to 5 produces...
Adding 1 to 3 produces...
Adding 1 to 1 produces...
Adding 1 to 5 produces...
The right answer: 6
Adding 1 to 3 produces...
The right answer: 4
Adding 1 to 1 produces...
The right answer: 2
```

Notice how "The wrong answer: 6" was printed right away, before you ever called the `add1_wrong` function? The way the code is written, it looks like the author *intended* to put the `printfn "The wrong answer"` line inside the `add1_wrong` function, but he made an indentation mistake and put it *outside* the function instead. So it gets run at the same time as the rest of the code that sets the `x`, `y`, and `z` variables and calls `add1_wrong` and `add1_right`.

If you don't yet understand what's going on in that sample code, **stop reading now** and keep reading it until you understand it. (Or ask a followup question if you still don't understand it after two or three readthroughs, because that means that I haven't explained it very well). It's important that you see the indentation mistake in my sample code before proceeding, because the code you posted has the same mistake in it. Actually, you have two indentation mistakes, but only one of them is causing the problem you've asked us about.

Here's your `main()` function, exactly as you typed it in this question, with the two indentation mistakes in it:

```
let main() =
  choosePuzzleMaker() 
  puzzleGuess() 
 c <- guess b [([],(0,0))] 
  while a <> c && d <> 8 do
    c <- guess b [(c, validate a c)] 
    d <- d+1 
  if d <> 8 then
    printfn "GZ! FUCKING MASTERMIND! You completed in %A turns and the code was %A" d a
  else
    printfn "That didn't go well...?"
    printfn "Game Over!"
PlayAgain()
main()
```

And now, here's the same function, with both indentation mistakes solved:

```
let main() =
  choosePuzzleMaker() 
  puzzleGuess() 
  c <- guess b [([],(0,0))] 
  while a <> c && d <> 8 do
    c <- guess b [(c, validate a c)] 
    d <- d+1 
  if d <> 8 then
    printfn "GZ! FUCKING MASTERMIND! You completed in %A turns and the code was %A" d a
  else
    printfn "That didn't go well...?"
    printfn "Game Over!"
    PlayAgain()
main()
```

The `c <- guess b [([],(0,0))]` line has been indented to match the other lines, and the `PlayAgain()` call at the end has been indented to be *inside* your `main()` function, instead of *outside* it the way you originally wrote it.

This is what Mark Seemann meant when he wrote in the comments that "the program only calls `PlayAgain` once". The way you wrote it, the `PlayAgain` function is **not** called at the end of `main()`. Instead, you were calling it *once*, then calling `main()` once, and then exiting your program.

By the way, there are lots of other things that I (and other experienced F# programmers) would suggest doing differently in your code -- for example, the names `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` aren't good names, because they don't give you a clue about what's supposed to be in those names. I'd suggest renaming them as follows:

- `a` should be called `correctAnswer`
- `b` should be called... actually, I haven't a clue what `b` is. I know it's passed into the `guess` function, but I have no idea how it gets used. And that, by the way, is why it's a bad variable name. Even if I don't see any code that uses it, the name alone should give me a clue as to *how* it's intended to be used.
- `c` should be called `thisGuess`
- `d` should be called `rounds` or `numberOfGuesses`.

Hope that helps you figure out (and fix) your mistake. Let us know if you need further help.

**UPDATE**: To answer your latest comment, there's a simple solution to your problem, and a clever solution. I'll show you both, because the clever solution will teach you a very valuable programming technique that's used *all the time* in functional programming languages like F#.

First, the simple solution. In F#, if you need to have two functions that call each other, that's called *mutual recursion*, and there are two keywords that you'd use to support it: the `rec` and `and` keywords. It looks like this:

```
// Note that these two functions would form an infinite loop!
let rec f x =
    g (x + 1)
and g x =
    f (x * 2)
```

The `rec` keyword tells the F# compiler "The function I'm defining is going to be calling itself, directly or indirectly, at some point -- so please make its name available within the function itself." The `and` keyword creates a *group* of functions that *all* have their names available to each other.

So one way you *could* solve this is to do the following:

```
let rec PlayAgain() =
    // ...
and main() =
    // ...
```

That would work, but I recommend a second solution. One of the key ideas in functional programming is *treating functions as "things" that you can manipulate*. That is, you can store functions in lists or arrays, pass them as parameters to other functions, and so on. Which brings us to a very powerful technique for taking a function like your `PlayAgain` function, and making it more general and re-useable. If a function like `PlayAgain` has the general structure "Do some calculations or make a decision. Then, depending on what the results were, either do A or B next" -- then what you do is *make A and B **parameters** of the function*! In other words, you turn it from a function that takes no parameters into a function that takes one or two parameters, where the parameters are the "what to do next" functions. (Normally you'd take two parameters in a function that decides between two scenarios. But in the case of your `PlayAgain` function, one of the two "what to do next" steps is "do nothing", so it makes sense to have it take only one parameter). This is known as *continuation-passing style* -- "continuation" is the traditional functional-programming terminology for any "what to do next" step.

Here's what that would look like:

```
let rec PlayAgain whatToDoNext =
  printfn "Do you want to play again? Please type:
1: Yes
2: No\n"
  match System.Console.ReadLine() with
  | "1"|"yes"|"Yes" -> printfn "Alright!!!"
                       whatToDoNext()

  | "2"|"no"|"No" -> printfn "The game is over!"

  | _   -> printfn "Invalid option! Please try again!"
           (PlayAgain())
```

That's it! All I did was give `PlayAgain` a parameter, and then *call* that parameter in the appropriate place. Now we rewrite your `main()` function as follows (changing just the last line, and using `let rec` so that the name `main` will be available inside the `main()` function):

```
let rec main() =
  choosePuzzleMaker() 
  puzzleGuess() 
 c <- guess b [([],(0,0))] 
  while a <> c && d <> 8 do
    c <- guess b [(c, validate a c)] 
    d <- d+1 
  if d <> 8 then
    printfn "GZ! FUCKING MASTERMIND! You completed in %A turns and the code was %A" d a
  else
    printfn "That didn't go well...?"
    printfn "Game Over!"
    PlayAgain main
```

And with that, you've avoided the use of `and`, *and* you've discovered a powerful new programming technique. I strongly recommend that F# beginners avoid using the `and` keyword if possible, because it tends to add unnecessary complication to reading the code later. And, as in this case, it can often be avoided by simply making the "what to do next" step a parameter, which also means that the `PlayAgain` function will be more easily reused as-is in later programs.

Comment: Arhh i see! Thanks for the help! And yeah the names was a bit lazy of me you're right. :) and the    c <- guess b [([],(0,0))] was a formatting error i just realized, sorry!

Comment: Hm, now it doesn't seem like Playagain() actually does anything... Did i mess up when i tried to define it?

Comment: In `Playagain()`, when the user chooses "yes", you run the `choosePuzzleMaker` function. But I think you meant to run `main` instead, right? You meant for them to go through the whole process of choosing a puzzle, then guessing the answer, right? I think that's your next problem.

Comment: Yes exactly, however as main is not defined yes i cant put it inside the PlayAgain() function, and if i define main first i can't put PlayAgain() inside of it! argh!

Comment: @Levicia - I just updated my answer to show you a solution to the "I can't call `main()` from inside `PlayAgain()`" dilemma you're struggling with. Two answers, actually, but I recommend the second one.